# Radio buttons in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am creating a quiz app in django. here is the model:

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    question = models.TextField()
    hint = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Each question can only have one answer.** This is where the problem comes in. I haven't been able to figure out how to write the admin form for **Option** model such that *for each question, only one of the options can have correct=True.*

I can use radio buttons for each question but don't know how to restrict them such that only one can be selected for one foreign key.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Can we see your "admin.py" file? Also, your `Option` model's `__unicode__` method isn't returning a valid value.

Comment: Use [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect). It's like a normal drop down, it just gives you the option to save one value.

Answer (score 2):

I understood your question like this: you want to change your code because only one option should be right.
Why don't you add this line to Question:

```
right_answer = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

Like this, you needn't the boolean `correct`. Your also could add a Manager to this who returns any option which should be chooseable (you override the method `get_queryset()`, and this manager should have this line at get_qeryset(): `q.option_set.all()` where q is there Question. (Without this any option, although its matched with another Question, could be marked.)

I'm not sure whether the secont part would work neither whether its a good way, but the first part is the important one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how that can be done with reverse look up.

I know this is not exactly what you want, but is quite close.
Can you go ahead and try this in the admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Quiz)
#admin.site.register(Option) #Include this if required

class OptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Option

@admin.register(Question)
    class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        OptionInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RadioSelect widget with admin integration .

```
class SimpleAdmin:
    ...
    form SimpleForm
    fields = (..., 'my_option', ...)
    ...
```

Create the form with the extra options:

```
class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Simple
    my_option = ChoiceField(
        label = 'Options',
        choices = (
            (0, 'num 0'),
            (1, 'num 1'),
        ),
        initial = 0,
        widget = RadioSelect,
    )
```

You can see [here](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-turn-django-admin-into-a-lightweight-dashboard-a0e0bbf609ad) a similar example with a chart into admin area

Answer (score 0):

```
class FooAdmin:
    form FooForm
    fields = ('gender', .....)

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
    gender = ChoiceField(
        label = 'Options',
        choices = (
            (0, 'Male'),
            (1, 'Female'),
        ),
        initial = 0,
        widget = RadioSelect,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take choices for question and register model in admin panel look below code.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    question = models.TextField()
    hint = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

and in Option class add choices that you want to give

```
OPTIONS = (
     (choice1 : 'choice1'),
     (choice2 : 'choice2')
) 
class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=OPTIONS)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

After that perform migrations it will solve your problem.

For more information [Click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/)

Answer (score 0):

```
options = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

you can take reference of above code